# How do I remove $ sign from string using replace?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, replace, dollar-sign

I cannot remove the dollar sign from the balance properties, I am not sure what I am missing? I thought it was string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)??

```js
const data = [{
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$100",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$120",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$80",
  },
];

const balances = data.map((amount) => {
  var newAmount = amount.replace("$", "");
  console.log(newAmount);
});
```

What I want:

```
100
120
80
```

Comment: your `map` returns nothing, your `amount` is an object, not a reference to the `balance` 
 property in the object.

Comment: `amount` is an object. Consider accessing a property on it `amount.balance`?

Comment: yes ....i feel ashamed. wasnt seeing it. thank you

Comment: @lache no need for shame. we learn, we move on

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to get the balance property of each item.

```js
const data = [{
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$100",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$120",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$80",
  },
];

data.forEach((item) => {
  var newAmount = item.balance.replace("$", "");
  console.log(newAmount);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check the following code

```js
const data = [{
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$100",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$120",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$80",
  },
];
const modifiedData = data.map((amount) => {
const oldBalance=amount.balance;// here we cache old value
 amount.balance=oldBalance.replace("$", "");// here we assign the modified value
console.log(amount.balance);

return amount;
});

console.log(modifiedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot the .balance thanks yall

```
const data = [{
    index: "14",
    name: "Bob",
    balance: "$100",
  },
  {
    index: "23",
    name: "John",
    balance: "$120",
  },
  {
    index: "17",
    name: "Steve",
    balance: "$80",
  },
];

const balances = data.map((amount) => {
  var newAmount = amount.balance.replace("$", "");
  console.log(newAmount);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please work with this code snippet. I hope this code works well with you.

```
const balances = data.map((amount) => {
    const newAmount = amount[balance].replace("$", "");
    console.log(newAmount)
})
```

Comment: I need to use return statement in the map, but it's just for example, so i used console log instead of return. Thanks.